# Plot parametric mean in R

Tags: r

I have a large real 1-d data set called r. 
I would like plot:

```
 mean(log(1+a*r)) vs a, with a > -1 .
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to evaluate the function on a set of values.

```
x <- seq(-1,1,length=20)
y <- sapply(x, function(a) mean(log(1+a*r)) )
plot(x,y, type="l")
```

Alternatively, you can define a function to compute this quantity
and use `curve` to plot it.
The function has to be vectorized.

```
r <- runif(100)
f <- function(a) mean(log(1+a*r))
f <- Vectorize(f)
curve(f, xlim=c(-1,1), las=1)
```

Comment: Vincent you are the king of R :)

Comment: How can i do with two data set r' and r'' and with two parameters a,b?
namely mean(log(1+a*r'+b*r'')) vs a,b

Comment: To plot a function of two variables,
you can use `persp`, `image`, `contour`
(or `levelplot`, `contourplot` in the `lattice` package).
To build the data, you can use `outer` and `Vectorize`.

Comment: I'm trying to use outer, but seems to me that doesn't accepts parametric functions. isn't it?

Comment: The argument of `outer` has to be a function, not an expression. And this function has to accept vectors: if it does not, you can try `outer(xs, ys, Vectorize(f))`.

Comment: i have tried this:
x <- seq(-1,1,length=20);

f1 <- sapply(x, function(a) mean(log(1+a*r1)) );

f2 <- sapply(x, function(b) mean(log(1+b*r2)) );

ff<-outer(f1,f2,mean(log(1+f1+f2)));

Comment: The last argument of `outer` should be a function: in your example, it is a (single) number.
You can try:
`f <- function(a,b) mean(log(1+a*r1+b*r2));
outer(x,x,Vectorize(f))`.